# injecting template class interface in the spring bean xml file

Tags: spring

i am using template interface to cast to the required DAO, but i need to place it in the bean xml file so that i can inject the datasource in the required implemented class.

### SimpleInterfaceDao.java

```
package com.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.connection.impl.QuerySpecifierWrapperList;

 public interface SimpleInterfaceDao<T>  {
    public List<String> loadColumnNames(String query);
    public List<T> loadAll(String query);   

}
```

### ClusterInfoDaoImpl.java

```
    package com.dao.impl;

    import java.util.List;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

    import com.common.CommonConstants;
    import com.connection.impl.QueryExecutorImpl;
    import com.connection.impl.QuerySpecifierWrapperList;
    import com.dao.ClusterInfo;
    import com.dao.SimpleInterfaceDao;

    public class ClusterInfoDaoImpl <T> implements SimpleInterfaceDao <T> {

        @Autowired
        DataSource GlobalcashmanmdataSource;


        static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ClusterInfoDaoImpl.class.getName());

        public List<T> loadAll(String query){
            List<ClusterInfo> listClusterinfo  =  null;

            log.info("Executing query loadAll:" + query);

            //JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = (JdbcTemplate) GlobalcashmanmdataSource;
            JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(GlobalcashmanmdataSource); 

            listClusterinfo  = jdbcTemplate.query(query,new BeanPropertyRowMapper<ClusterInfo>(ClusterInfo.class));

            return (List <T>) listClusterinfo;
        }

        public List<String> loadColumnNames(String query){
            List<String> columnNames = null;

            //TODO to be removed or commented once the testing is done.
            //callContextToSetDataSource();

            JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(GlobalcashmanmdataSource); 
            columnNames  = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query,String.class);

            return columnNames;
        }

        public void insert(ClusterInfo customer){

        }
    }
```

### call to the function

```
public class QueryExecutorImpl {

public QueryExecutionResults executeQueryWrapperByQueryID(String queryID){
......
......

            SimpleInterfaceDao <ClusterInfo> daoInterface =  new  ClusterInfoDaoImpl<ClusterInfo>();

                queryColumnNames = daoInterface.loadColumnNames(querySpecifier.getColumnQuery());
                queryRowColResult =    (List) daoInterface.loadAll(querySpecifier.getColumnQuery());


......              

}
```

### bean.xml

```
  <bean id="queryexecutorimplbean" class="com.connection.impl.QueryExecutorImpl">
  </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is not clear, However you could try this way

If `ClusterInfoDaoImpl` bean, already been created then it's simple, inject this directly into `QueryExecutorImpl` (have a instance `ClusterInfoDaoImpl<?> daoInterface; and it's setter property`)

```
<bean id="queryexecutorimplbean" class="com.connection.impl.QueryExecutorImpl">
<property name="ClusterInfoDao" ref="ClusterInfoDaoImpl" />
  </bean>
```

I think nothing much to do with templates here.

Comment: help need how to define the ClusterInfoDaoImp template bean and injecting in the QueryExecutorImpl

Comment: @Gopal It's same as normal bean, Spring has no generic type  support, However  the compiler just creates a Class Cast Exception in that case . So the solution is:`<bean id="ClusterInfoDaoImpl" class="com.connection.impl.ClusterInfoDaoImpl">
<property name="GlobalcashmanmdataSource" ref="GlobalcashmanmdataSources" />
  </bean>` Please correct me if I am wrong.